# pcmpestri instruction to write similar strpos function?

Tags: c++, assembly, sse, strpos, sse4

How can the `pcmpestri` instruction be used to write a function similar to `strpos` function in C++? I can use g++ compiler.

`pcmpestri` is a new instruction that is found in SSE4

Comment: Can you show an attempt - or add some details? The way it is right now, this question is structurally very similar to all those "write me a function in Java that reverses a string" questions, even if at a somewhat higher level...

Comment: I thought it was "lower level", since it involves assembler instructions? ;)

Comment: `pcmpistri` is faster and can probably do it too. Look at EQUAL_ORDERED. I would give a better answer, but I don't have a CPU that supports SSE 4.2 so I can't test anything.

Answer (score -3):

Before using the SSE instructions you have to store away the floating point stack, and restore afterwards. That is costly, unless your strings are *huge* it won't be worth it. And for huge strings, better algorithms are the way to go (Boyer-Moore or such).

Comment: This was true for MMX.  It is not the case with SSE (that you need to do EMMS; obviously one should still consider sub-quadratic algorithms)